# Keep getting the password complexity error for a OU that should have it disabled

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have a specific Organizational Unit in my Active Directory domain that needs to have weak password settings. I set up my GPO and created a new policy for the OU `OU=Limited Users,OU=Production,OU=VetWeb,DC=vw,DC=local` called "GPO for Limited Production Users". According to Group Policy Modeling I did set up everything correctly.

[image]

However when I try to create a new user or change the password on a existing user with a password that would not meet complexity requirements I get a error message. For example resetting the password for the user `CN=Test,OU=Limited Users,OU=Production,OU=VetWeb,DC=vw,DC=local` to the password of 12345 gives me the error that the new password does not meet the password complexity requirements.

[image]

Doing a `gpupdate /force` does not resolve the issue. What must I do to allow users in `OU=Limited Users,OU=Production,OU=VetWeb,DC=vw,DC=local` not to require complex passwords?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't set a password policy for an OU this way. The password policy for the entire domain is defined in the Default Domain Policy. It cannot be overridden at a per-OU level through Group Policy. What you want is a [Fine Grained Password Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx), which is a bit more complicated to configure, but is the **only** way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: And just to add some detail to this answer, Fine Grained Password policies can't be applied to an OU.  They're only applied to users directly or via groups that users are a member of.

Comment: What can help with that is to use the concept of a shadow group, which mirrors the members of an OU.

Comment: Shadow groups only mirror the members of an OU for as long as the domain admins are diligent about keeping them up to date.  Sadly, there's no built-in way to automate this.